# Django - delete button is not redirecting to the correct path

Tags: python, django, forms, redirect, button

I am following a tutorial to make a to-do list website. Upon trying to implement a delete button, I am encountering this error.

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://localhost:8000/%7B%25%20url%20'delete'%20things.id%20%25
>   Using the URLconf defined in todo.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order: 
>   admin/ [name='home'] delete/"" [name='delete'] The current
>   path, {% url 'delete' things.id %, didn't match any of these.

Relevant code:
**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import List
from .forms import ListForm
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ListForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            all_items = List.objects.all
            messages.success(request, ('Item Has Been Added To List!'))
            return render(request, 'home.html', {'all_items': all_items})

    else:
        all_items = List.objects.all
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'all_items': all_items})

def delete(request, list_id):
    item = List.objects.get(pk=list_id)
    item.delete()
    messages.success(request, ('Item Has Been Deleted!'))
    return redirect('home')
```

**home.html**

```
<tr>
            <td>{{ things.item }}</td>
            <td><center>{{ things.completed }}</center></td>
            <td><center><a href = "{% url 'delete' things.id %}"> Delete</a></center></td>
</tr>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('delete/<list_id>', views.delete, name="delete"),
]
```

Comment: Please show the code of `views.home`.

Comment: I have added it to the main post

Comment: Don't you need `path('delete/(?P<list_id>)/$', views.delete, name="delete"),` instead?

Comment: @MattCremeens
The error stays the same and says:
Using the URLconf defined in todo.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='home']
delete/(?P<list_id>)/$ [name='delete']
The current path, {% url 'delete' things.id %, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Please see my answer. I believe this should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('delete/<int:list_id>/', views.delete, name="delete"),
]
```

You need to specify the `int` type in the url.

And also the trailing `/`

Comment: I edit the answer, you also need to have that trailing '/' in order for django to find that.

Comment: The error still prevails now showing the changes I made

Comment: Update: This worked. Apparently, stupid me though just refreshing at the error should restart the server and fix the error but I started again from localhost:8000 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need a regular expression to say a number is coming

```
path('delete/(?P<list_id>)[\d]+)/$', views.delete, name="delete"),
```

Comment: The error is still there, now mentioning the new URL pattern instead. Could it be something to do with the href tag in html?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/MZohEWx.png?1

A warning that is shown in the cmd prompt where I have run the server